What's the reason behind negative selection of questions on MSE?
There's been a noticeable trend going for the last two years. Mathematically sound questions are usually closed pretty swiftly if there's even a slight chance of tagging them as so-called PSQ or a question lacking context, whilst all the homework questions, provided they are sufficiently verbose, remain open, despite being almost surely answerable by a 15-minute search for similar ones already answered here.
There's an obvious strategy to avoid this PSQ branding: using LLM to generate sufficiently long paragraphs of nonsense, and maybe trim some of the obvious signs of being generated.
Some people are arguing against PSQ questions by saying that

they cannot be distinguished from someone simply copying a question
from a test they wish to cheat on.

But it is clearly the problem of a person trying to remove such questions! If a person sucks so bad at differentiating test problems from more or less meaningful but sincere questions — why do they even try?
And, as it's usually harder to explain what's exactly hard to understand, tendency to reward verbiage and punish clarity only reinforces MSE as a place to get homework solutions.
So, how exactly preference for trivial, long-winded questions which were already answered a hundred times, serves the purpose of this site — as far as I remember it, it's something along the lines of "collecting high quality answers"?
Most people who are competent enough to write a high-quality answer will, presumably, seek an opportunity to write something which cannot be found in every textbook on group theory; something which is worth spending time on.
So, the question: if the goals of the site have not drastically changed from collecting high-quality answers, how exactly removal of nontrivial questions and keeping the flood of trivialities helps to achieve it?

Would maybe some of these tags be suitable here: ([meta-tag:closing]), ([meta-tag:context]) and perhaps ([meta-tag:down-votes])? The tag (down-votes) is probably a stretch - and only five tags are allowed, after all. The tag (context) is the closest to the topic of PSQ that I was able to think of.

PSQ closure is an outdated (and nonoptimal) way to control quality. Instead we should be using duplicate closure, since most PSQs are also dupes by now (though this was not true in the early days). Interesting questions that are not dupes will add knowledge to the site so should not be closed (even if they are PSQs). This is generally how I strive to moderate in my tags. But, alas, this won't work generally until we can convince enough users to invest the large amount of time needed to search for dupes (hundreds of times more effort than a PSQ closure click).

The above method has a major advantage: PSQ closure add no value to the site, but dupe closure serves greatly to organize the site by adding links, e.g. to specializations, generalizations, (counter)examples, etc. Further it sparks review and organization of the linked dupes, leading to iterative refinement of prior threads (hopefully, eventually leading to "proofs from the book"). $\ \ $

You make many assertions, xsnl, with no evidence or even an example to support them. Anyway, I hope you are doing your best to root out duplicates and to vote to close them.

@GerryMyerson Is your comment a subtle hint that my assertions are wrong? In any case, my point is that keeping (potentially) good questions is more important than closing (potentially) bad ones. So not only my assertions are wrong, but also the whole point is just invalid, because high reputation user said so. Is this interpretation right?

I am a mathematician. My comment means what it says, no more and no less.
